# Java version to reflect application java not container java

Tags: java, docker, docker-container

We have a requirement where the java version to be executed on pod terminal to show the application java version not the container version.
We are using base docker image which has jdk 1.8 and copies the jdk11 library within it for the application to use jdk 11. When I execute java -version in pod terminal it shows jdk 1.8

Already tried of setting java_home and path correctly to jdk 11 location, but still the java version shows jdk 1.8

Comment: Why not use a base docker image with 11?

Comment: We cannot use that as that is a custom image built and we cannot use the public images in the company

Comment: What's a "pod terminal"?  Why do you want `java -version` to show something other than the version of the `/usr/bin/java` installation?  Why can't you update your locally-built JVM base image to have the right version of Java?

Comment: True.. ideally we should, but we have some restrictions and can't do that in my organization.

Comment: meaning you cant even build a new JDK 11 image yourself? if that's the case have you tried replacing the binaries of JDK 1.8 with the ones for JDK 11? otherwise, what are you able to do or what restrictions are you facing?

Comment: We have few compliances to use the images from the list, we are using jdk 11 binaries and pointed java home and path accordingly. But due to other compliance java version should reflect the application version and that is not the case. We have some restrictions in organisation

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue sounds independent of docker, it just appears in your docker container. I understand you start off from a JDK8 image just to install your own version of JDK11.

- You could start from an image without any JDK and still install your own, which would get you around the confusion.
- You could still start from the JDK8 image and replace the JDK in the container, again eliminating any confusion which of the JDKs is running
- If you want to stay the way you have it now, change the path inside the container to first list your JDK11 before the existing JDK8. Then your calls to version will give your targeted JVM.

So you can see all these ideas would be the same if you had JDK8 installed on a machine and want to install and run your application with a different JDK. The problem is the same, and solutions to this are also the same.